# SQL Запрос на фильтрацию по приоритетному полу

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть таблица `movements`
У нее есть поля `flight_id, shipment_id, status_code`

примерные данные:

```
flight_id, shipment_id, status_code
126155;6033;"MAN"
126155;6008;"MAN"
126155;6040;"MAN"
126155;6041;"BKD"
126155;6008;"RCF"
126155;6033;"BKD"
126155;6008;"BKD"
126155;6040;"PRE"
```

я хочу найти все `movements` с каким-то конкретным `flight_id`
затем сгруппировать их по `shipment_id`
и с каждой группы `movements.shipment_id` оставить только один `movement`
согласно приоритету для `status_code`

у меня получился такой код:

```
SELECT flight_id, shipment_id, status_code
FROM movements
WHERE flight_id = 126155
AND (flight_id, shipment_id)
  IN
  (
    SELECT flight_id, shipment_id
    FROM movements
    GROUP BY flight_id, shipment_id
  )
ORDER BY shipment_id, CASE
  WHEN status_code = 'RCF' THEN 0
  WHEN status_code = 'PRE' THEN 1
  WHEN status_code = 'MAN' THEN 2
  WHEN status_code = 'BKD' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END DESC
```

на выходе я получаю:

```
flight_id, shipment_id, status_code
126155;6008;"BKD"
126155;6008;"MAN"
126155;6008;"RCF"

126155;6033;"BKD"
126155;6033;"MAN"

126155;6040;"MAN"
126155;6040;"PRE"

126155;6041;"BKD"
```

но я хочу отбросить все не нужное и получить:

```
flight_id, shipment_id, status_code
126155;6008;"RCF"
126155;6033;"MAN"
126155;6040;"PRE"
126155;6041;"BKD"
```

грубо говоря у каждого `shipment_id` последний согласно приоритету `movement.status_code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У postgresql есть подходящее для этой задачи расширение стандарта `distinct on`.

```
SELECT distinct on (shipment_id) flight_id, shipment_id, status_code
FROM movements
WHERE flight_id = 126155
ORDER BY shipment_id, CASE
  WHEN status_code = 'RCF' THEN 0
  WHEN status_code = 'PRE' THEN 1
  WHEN status_code = 'MAN' THEN 2
  WHEN status_code = 'BKD' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END DESC
```

distinct пока ещё не умеет loose index scan, что не слишком хорошо для больших и не селективных таблиц, зато простой в чтении и понимании. Более быстрый способ [немного посложнее](https://pgday.ru/files/pgmaster14/max.boguk.query.optimization.pdf)

Comment: Это то что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT flight_id, shipment_id, status_code
FROM movements
WHERE flight_id = 126155
GROUP BY flight_id, shipment_id   
ORDER BY shipment_id, CASE
  WHEN status_code = 'RCF' THEN 0
  WHEN status_code = 'PRE' THEN 1
  WHEN status_code = 'MAN' THEN 2
  WHEN status_code = 'BKD' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END DESC
```

Comment: и что это даст?

Comment: Получаем все данные, где `flight_id = 126155`, группируем их по полю `shipment_id`, сортируем согласно условиям. Группировка позволит получить только первое значение `status_code`

Comment: но группировка вызовет ошибку status_code, поэтому я и делал AND IN

Comment: Почему вызовет ошибку? Вы же отсортировали поля по `status_code`

Comment: `ERROR:  column "movements.status_code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: В теории `status_code` можно сделать `ENUM`, а потом просто `SELECT flight_id, shipment_id, max(status_code) as status_code
FROM movements
WHERE flight_id = 126155
GROUP BY flight_id, shipment_id   
ORDER BY shipment_id`